# how to catch up exception when user click links in textview?

Tags: android

use a TextView to show email, and set

```
TextView tvEmail = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
Linkify.addLinks(tvEmail, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
```

click on above mail address will raise an exception, because mail client didn't found. how to catch up this exception?

Comment: which exception is there on textview click?

Comment: @PareshMayani ActivityNotFound, No Activity found to handle Intent {act=android.intent.action.View dat=mailto:xxx }

Answer (score 2):

I have already had the same issue, and I solved it by creating a new class that checks for `null` before actually launching the `Intent`.

All you have to do is to replace all `URLSpan` spans, before setting the `TextView`'s text (which means you cannot use `setAutoLinkMask()`).

This has to be done, because `URLSpan`'s `onClick()` method does not perform any kind of `null` checks.

How to preceed:

```
TextView txt = ...
txt.setLinksClickable(true);
txt.setText(SafeURLSpan.parseSafeHtml(<<YOUR STRING GOES HERE>>));
txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Kinds of strings that could be used in `<<YOUR STRING GOES HERE>>`:

```
"Click here: <a href=\"http://google.com\">My links</a>"
"Mail me: <a href=\"mailto:john@doe.com\">My email</a>"
... and so on...
```

Here is the source for `SafeURLSPan` class (I use it in my app [FPlay](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid), and it has been tested on Android 10+):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.style.URLSpan;
import android.view.View;

public final class SafeURLSpan extends URLSpan {
    public SafeURLSpan(String url) {
        super(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        try {
            final Uri uri = Uri.parse(getURL());
            final Context context = widget.getContext();
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            if (context != null && intent != null) {
                intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, context.getPackageName());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
        }
    }

    public static CharSequence parseSafeHtml(CharSequence html) {
        return replaceURLSpans(Html.fromHtml(html.toString()));
    }

    public static CharSequence replaceURLSpans(CharSequence text) {
        if (text instanceof Spannable) {
            final Spannable s = (Spannable)text;
            final URLSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class);
            if (spans != null && spans.length > 0) {
                for (int i = spans.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    final URLSpan span = spans[i];
                    final int start = s.getSpanStart(span);
                    final int end = s.getSpanEnd(span);
                    final int flags = s.getSpanFlags(span);
                    s.removeSpan(span);
                    s.setSpan(new SafeURLSpan(span.getURL()), start, end, flags);
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```