# No Activity found to handle Intent action.VIEW when clicking email link

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, html-email

I got this new crash exception after the newest app update.  It seems to not point anywhere. Would anyone be able to tell what the issue is? It looks like a possible email-formatting issue due to this: dat=mailto:xxxx@xxxxxxxxx.xxx (has extras) ....but I am not sure I have any errors in emails.

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
dat=mailto:xxxx@xxxxxxxxx.xxx (has extras) }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
        at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
        at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:212)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8344)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1912)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5722)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2897)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2473)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2482)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you!

Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage"
    android:versionCode="123"
    android:versionName="1.2.3" >

    <supports-screens  android:largeScreens="true"   android:normalScreens="true"  android:smallScreens="true"/> 

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


    <permission android:name="com.problemio.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.problemio.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> 
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" 
        android:name="MyApplication"
                >

        <!--  For Google Cloud Messaging -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.problemio" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>   

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
        <!--  End of Google Cloud Messaging -->






        <activity
            android:name=".ProblemioActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AddProblemActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/add_problem" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login" />        

        <activity
            android:name=".MyProblemsActivity"
            android:label="@string/your_problems" /> 

        <activity
            android:name=".CreateProfileActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/create_account" />         

        <activity
            android:name=".ProblemActivity"
            android:label="@string/problem_page_header" />   


        <activity
            android:name=".WePromoteActivity"
            android:label="@string/we_promote" /> 

<!--  
        <activity
            android:name=".SuggestSolutionActivity"
            android:label="@string/suggest_solution_header" />  

        <activity
            android:name=".SuggestedSolutionActivity"
            android:label="@string/suggested_solution_header" />          

        <activity
            android:name=".ViewSolutionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/view_solutions_header" />        
-->        
        <activity
            android:name=".TopicActivity"
            android:label="@string/topic_header" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>         

        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/forgot_password_heading" />         

        <activity
            android:name=".AskQuestionActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/ask_question_heading" />         

        <activity
            android:name=".QuestionActivity"
            android:label="@string/question_header" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>     


        <activity
            android:name=".MyQuestionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/see_my_questions_header" />        



        <activity
            android:name=".LearnActivity"
            android:label="@string/learn_header" />         

        <activity
            android:name=".ExtraHelpActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/extra_help_header" />          

        <activity
            android:name=".content.AdvertisingActivity"
            android:label="@string/advertising_header" />           

        <activity
            android:name=".content.ProductStrategyActivity"
            android:label="@string/product_strategy_header" />         

        <activity
            android:name=".content.BusinessModelsActivity"
            android:label="@string/business_models_header" />           

        <activity
            android:name=".content.StageTacticsActivity"
            android:label="@string/stage_tactics_header" />         

        <activity
            android:name=".content.InvestorsActivity"
            android:label="@string/funding_header" />         


        <activity
            android:name=".content.TargetMarketActivity"
            android:label="@string/target_market_header" />           

        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings_header" />         

        <activity
            android:name=".content.BusinessIdeasActivity"
            android:label="@string/business_ideas" /> 

        <activity
            android:name=".content.MarketIdeaValidationActivity"
            android:label="@string/market_idea_validation" />         



        <activity
            android:name=".content.UnitEconomicsActivity"
            android:label="@string/unit_economics" />  

        <activity
            android:name=".content.PremiumWebAdvertisingActivity"
            android:label="@string/premium_web_marketing" />          

        <activity
            android:name=".content.PsychologyActivity"
            android:label="@string/business_psychology" />  

        <activity
            android:name=".NumberOfBusinessesActivity"
            android:label="@string/num_of_businesses" />          

        <activity
            android:name=".TimelineActivity"
            android:label="@string/timeline" />          

        <activity
            android:name=".content.PitchBusinessActivity"
            android:label="@string/pitch" />   

        <activity
            android:name=".content.TopMistakesActivity"
            android:label="@string/top_mistakes" />        

        <activity
            android:name=".content.MarktingAndConversionActivity"
            android:label="@string/marketing_and_conversion" />           

        <activity
            android:name=".content.HelpInstructionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/help_instructions" />          


        <activity
            android:name=".content.WebSetupActivity"
            android:label="@string/web_setup_page" />          


        <activity
            android:name=".UpdateProfileActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/update_profile" />           





        <activity
            android:name=".FeedbackActivity"
            android:label="@string/feedback" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/> 


        <activity
            android:name=".BaseActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".BaseListActivity"/> 

        <activity
            android:name=".EditBusinessActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/edit_business" />   

        <activity
            android:name=".TopicEditActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/topic_edit" />        

        <activity
            android:name=".InviteFriendsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/invite_friends" />

        <activity
            android:name=".EnterInviteCodeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/enter_invite_code" />        

        <activity
            android:name=".CommunityActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/community_page" />   

        <activity
            android:name=".CommunitySignupActivity"
            android:label="@string/community_signup" />           

        <activity
            android:name=".PlanExamplesActivity"
            android:label="@string/plan_examples" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/plan_examples" />        


        <activity
            android:name=".GiveBackActivity"
            android:label="@string/give_back" /> 

        <activity
            android:name=".MotivationActivity"
            android:label="@string/motivation_page" />         


        <activity
            android:name=".AdsActivity"
            android:label="@string/ads_activity" />         

        <activity
            android:name=".content.WebsiteServiceActivity"
            android:label="@string/website_service_activity" />         

        <activity
            android:name=".MoreArticlesActivity"
            android:label="@string/more_articles" />           

<!--         
        <service android:name="BillingService" />

        <receiver android:name="BillingReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>        
 -->

        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TJCOffersWebView" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TapjoyFullScreenAdWebView" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TapjoyDailyRewardAdWebView" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TapjoyVideoView" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />

        </application>

</manifest>
```

Could something like this be a problem:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contact_email"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop ="15dp" 
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:text="some@email.com"

    />
```

Comment: Can you post the Manifest file?

Comment: @Arash yes, which part of it? the activity setups? Or something else?

Comment: @Arash I just posted the whole file in the original question.

Comment: @Arash did I maybe need this permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> ...I saw it on another forum as a suggestion.

Comment: Maybe not CALL_PHONE but SEND_EMAIL or something like that?

Comment: @Genadinik: No the exception says an application cannot be found to handle the event.  So there was no application to look into the email and find wrong formatting. What is the application supposed to do with email? The combination of act=android.intent.action.VIEW and email address looks rather unusual.  To send an email, they seems to always use action.SEND.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: @full.stack.ex it is tough to say why it looks unusual since it does not point to where this happens.  I do have a setting like I just added to the original question.

Comment: @Genadinik: Sorry if it was unclear.  Try replacing android.intent.action.VIEW with android.intent.action.SEND and see what happens.  (The hypothesis is that the intent is wrong.)

Comment: @full.stack.ex sorry, but still a bit confused - which android.intent.action.VIEW were you talking about? And I am also confused what @ genadinik is doing there :)

Comment: @Genadinik: I guess you need to reformulate your question to avoid further guesses.  I inferred that your application calls some email-related external app to do something with email (view?).  To do so, it uses an intent, and that intent may be wrong.  The exception tells you just that: no app to VIEW the email:  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
dat=mailto:xxxx@xxxxxxxxx.xxx (has extras) } Did you mean anything else?

Comment: @full.stack.ex I think my problem is that I can not tell which activity is causing this exception.  Also, wouldn't the whole thing not compile if I tried to go to an activity that is not there?

Comment: @Genadinik: Yes it will compile.  The compiler doesn't know where the APK will be deployed.  Anyway, the question is indeed confusing, needs to be reworded.

Answer (score 8):

**Copied from my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26042099/3569421)**

I have already had the same issue, and I solved it by creating a new class that checks for `null` before actually launching the `Intent`.

All you have to do is to replace all `URLSpan` spans, before setting the `TextView`'s text (which means you cannot use `setAutoLinkMask()`).

This has to be done, because `URLSpan`'s `onClick()` method does not perform any kind of `null` checks.

How to preceed:

```
TextView txt = ...
txt.setLinksClickable(true);
txt.setText(SafeURLSpan.parseSafeHtml(<<YOUR STRING GOES HERE>>));
txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Kinds of strings that could be used in `<<YOUR STRING GOES HERE>>`:

```
"Click here: <a href=\"http://google.com\">My links</a>"
"Mail me: <a href=\"mailto:john@doe.com\">My email</a>"
... and so on...
```

Here is the source for `SafeURLSPan` class (I use it in my app [FPlay](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid), and it has been tested on Android 10+):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.style.URLSpan;
import android.view.View;

public final class SafeURLSpan extends URLSpan {
    public SafeURLSpan(String url) {
        super(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        try {
            final Uri uri = Uri.parse(getURL());
            final Context context = widget.getContext();
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            if (context != null && intent != null) {
                intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, context.getPackageName());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
        }
    }

    public static CharSequence parseSafeHtml(CharSequence html) {
        return replaceURLSpans(Html.fromHtml(html.toString()));
    }

    public static CharSequence replaceURLSpans(CharSequence text) {
        if (text instanceof Spannable) {
            final Spannable s = (Spannable)text;
            final URLSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class);
            if (spans != null && spans.length > 0) {
                for (int i = spans.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    final URLSpan span = spans[i];
                    final int start = s.getSpanStart(span);
                    final int end = s.getSpanEnd(span);
                    final int flags = s.getSpanFlags(span);
                    s.removeSpan(span);
                    s.setSpan(new SafeURLSpan(span.getURL()), start, end, flags);
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will lead to error: RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel . I created a gist for detail https://gist.github.com/meidikawardana/6b17c79c8b51ba39bc704c84316631df

Comment: @Dika That's really curious. As I said, I have been using this solution myself in my app for a few years now https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid/blob/master/src/br/com/carlosrafaelgn/fplay/ActivityAbout.java The snippet you shared contains only the exception's stack trace. Could you submit the code where that exception happened?

Comment: I got the error from crashlytics report (https://fabric.io/kits/crashlytics). as you can see, my error snippet does not inform where the error happened. but the error happened after I add your snippet, exactly as what you shared. so I remove your snippet and the error disappears.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem as well, the thing is that when you define:

```
android:autoLink="email"
android:text="some@email.com"
```

or any other type of autolink in a TextView, android handles everything for you.

In the emulator email is not setup by default, so there is no app to handle the intent, and this makes your app crash if you click an autolinked email address. If you open the mail app and follow the instructions to set it up, then when you click the email address it will work.

I don't know what you can do to work around this issue. I guess it might not be safe to assume the user has mail setup or at least one app capable of handling that intent. I also guess that the app shouldn't be crashing... I think this is an issue with android as in this case you have no way of handling the exception.

If you look at the source of URLSpan (If autolink is set, TextView uses android.text.util.Linkify.addLinks(..) which creates instances of URLSpan to create links):
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/text/style/URLSpan.java#URLSpan

```
public void onClick(View widget) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(getURL());
    Context context = widget.getContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, context.getPackageName());
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

They could either handle the exception or use PackageManager to determine if the Intent would succeed before calling startActivity() (like they recommend: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#Verify) or use a chooser.

> Although the Android platform guarantees that certain intents will resolve to one of the built-in apps (such as the Phone, Email, or Calendar app), you should always include a verification step before invoking an intent.
>
> Caution: If you invoke an intent and there is no app available on the device that can handle the intent, your app will crash.

So my question would be: is there any guarantee that an email intent will always resolve on a real device?

ok... on the same section they also mention:

> Note: You should perform this check when your activity first starts in case you need to disable the feature that uses the intent before the user attempts to use it. If you know of a specific app that can handle the intent, you can also provide a link for the user to download the app (see how to link to your product on Google Play).

One can always check if the intent resolves to any activity at the start of the application, set a flag and every time the layout containing such TextView is inflated we find it and disable auto link for email, etc. (and this is when I ponder killing an unicorn over coding that)

Answer (score 1):

By the way no email client can occur if no email account is set up on the device so technically this can occur on real devices as well.
Here is the code for disabling the AutoLink if not available as suggested by novettam:

```
protected boolean checkIntent(Intent intent)
{
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> apps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    return apps.size() > 0 && !( apps.get(0).activityInfo.name.equals(activity.getClass().getName()) && apps.size() == 1) ;
}


protected Intent createDummyEmailIntent()
{
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto", "abc@gmail.com", null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "EXTRA_SUBJECT");
    return emailIntent;
}

protected Intent createDummyWebIntent()
{
    final Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.co.uk"));
    return webIntent;
}

protected Intent createDummyPhoneIntent(){
    String uri = "tel:" + "0131 666 7777".trim() ;
    final Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    return phoneIntent;
}
//Checking
if ( !checkIntent(intent) ) {
            textview.setAutoLinkMask(0);
}
//be sure that you call setText after this
```